# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'model'

Tags: django, django-models

i am making simple model in videorequest app

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class video(models.Model):
    videotitle = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    videodesc = models.TextField()
    dateadded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Name: {},Id: {}'.format(self.videotitle,self.id)
```

what's wrong in my code
cmd showing me while i am trying to run python manage.py runserver query

Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x0446E7C8>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
      fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
      autoreload.raise_last_exception()
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
      raise _exception[1]
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 337, in execute
      autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
      fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in setup
      apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
      app_config.import_models()
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
      self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
    File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
    File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
    File "", line 728, in exec_module
    File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "F:\python_project\05project\mywebsite\videorequest\models.py", line 4, in 
      class Video(models.model):
  AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'model'

Comment: That is not your code. Your code has `models.model`, not `models.Model`.

Comment: from where you are actually getting this error. Can you please add your `error-traceback`

Comment: when i try to run python manage.py runserver command @shakil

Comment: @DanielRoseman no my code have models.Model only

Comment: It is just fine when i ran. Which django version your are using?. Please add your error.

Comment: Your traceback clearly shows otherwise.

Comment: @bkawan did you mean what cmd is showing? i am new to django

Comment: your error itself is saying 
in class Video(**models.model**)

Answer (score 8):

*in line 4 in class Video(models.model): AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'model'*

I think you have typo mistake. models do not have model instead it have Model.
convert

**Convert**

```
Video(models.model)
```

**to**

```
Video(models.Model)
```

Comment: which django version you are using ?

Comment: Maybe you should point out that the problem is due to the Django version